# Can i get payments to my paypal account with help of paypal api

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to sell some non-physical product and get its payment directly into your personal paypal account? Has anyone did something like this?

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible, and actually very easy. What kind of integration are you looking for? Maybe one of the buttons at http://www.paypal.com/buttons would be a good start for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of a VERY Simple checkout Script using REST API (Client Side Only Code)
First add this line to "head" of your HTML page: 
      {

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client- 
        id=YOUR USER ID GOES HEREg&disable-funding=credit,card"></script>
```

}

Then add this to where you want your PayPal Button(s) to be on your HTML Page:

```
    '<div style="width:30%" id="paypal-button-container"><p style="font-size:small"> 
     <b>Checkout using your PayPal Acount <br>
     or if you do not have a PayPal Account, you can pay with your Debit or Credit 
     Card (option at bottom of Pop-up Window).</b></p></div>
   <script>
    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal.Buttons({
        onError: function (err) {
            alert('An Error Occured, returning you to the Form. Please Check that you 
     are not submitting a Zero Amount and have Filled out the Form');
        },
        style: {
          layout: 'horizontal',
          color: 'gold',
          shape: 'pill',
          label: 'checkout',
          size: 'responsive',
          tagline: 'true',
        },
        // Set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    description: 'GnG Order',
                    amount: {
                        value: cartTotal
                    }
                }]
            });
        },

        // Finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                // Show a success message to the buyer
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + 
         '!');
            });
            if (details.error === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
               return actions.restart();
            };
        }


       }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>'
```

That should do it for you.  Be sure to login to the Developer Panel to set up your API credentials.